# How can I quickly delete multiple messages at once in Discord?

Tags: discord

Is there an easy way to mass delete messages from a Discord channel? It's one of Discord's [most requested features](https://feedback.discordapp.com/forums/326712-discord-dream-land/suggestions/12808896-purge-chat) and is very helpful if a channel gets flooded with spam messages. The alternative is manually deleting almost every message in the server.

Comment: I have tried and tested this script here, which works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49462738/2139770

Answer (score 18):

Add [Mee6 bot](https://mee6.xyz/) to your Discord server. One of its moderator options is a !Clear command.

> Usage:
>   **!clear @someone** Delete the messages of @someone in the last 100 messages.
>   **!clear xx** Delete the xx last messages. Maximum of 1000. Higher numbers may take a while and can crash your discord on mobile devices.

---

Alternatively, if adding bots isn't an option, you can make manual deletion a bit easier by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>. This will skip the confirmation box that usually displays when deleting messages.

Comment: I have the Mee6 bot. It will mass delete messages, but only up to two weeks ago. If it's after 2 weeks ago, it won't delete the messages

Comment: Not work press holddown shift 

Comment: You can use this script without a bot to remove all your messages in a channel: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49462738/2139770

Comment: You have to buy the Premium feature of Mee6 bot to enable the "Moderator" plugin :(

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete all the messages from the channel, Clone then delete the channel.

If you need to delete more than 1000 messages that are less than 2 weeks old, my discord bot [PvPCraft](https://bot.pvpcraft.ca/docs) can help you, it's harder to use though so for less than 1000 I would go with mee6.